# How to read raw input values in Surface SDK (Pixelsense)

Tags: .net, wpf, sdk, pixelsense

So me and my project group are currently working on a prototype to use on the Microsoft PixelSense. More specifically we are looking at how light might trigger action on the table and we are therefore at a standstill, as the API does not seem to allow us to read raw values. 
For instance, we would like to see a value that indicates light intensity somehow. We know the table detects different light-frequencies, because it responds to different kinds of light, and we have tested this throughout in our research.

If anyone knows of anything in the API that we can use to read raw input data in some way, or has any creative solutions, please give us a hint.

PS: we are working in c#

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you need to show more effort on the solution before posting a Question, try posting what have you tried so far, which other sources of information have you looking form

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [RawImage Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727763.aspx) sample application. It uses the FrameReceivedEventArgs.TryGetRawImage and FrameReceivedEventArgs.UpdateRawImage methods available in Microsoft.Surface.Core

disclaimer: I've seen the RawImage Visualizer run, but haven't actually looked at the source code

**EDIT:** RawImage Visualizer uses XNA. If using WPF, see [Capturing Raw Images When Using WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727886.aspx) instead.